# Cannot find Python.h when configuring pycairo 1.10.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycairo

I am trying to setup pycairo in `virtualenv` but setup fails when searching for Python.h header file

```
(draw)[root@collabdraw pycairo]# python ./waf configure --prefix=/usr
  ./options()
Setting top to                           : /root/pycairo 
Setting out to                           : /root/pycairo/build_directory 
  ./configure()
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program python              : /root/virtualenvt/draw/bin/python 
Checking for python version              : (3, 2, 0, 'final', 0) 
Checking for library python3.2 in LIBDIR : not found 
Checking for library python3.2 in python_LIBPL : not found 
Checking for library python3.2 in $prefix/libs : not found 
Checking for library python32 in LIBDIR        : not found 
Checking for library python32 in python_LIBPL  : not found 
Checking for library python32 in $prefix/libs  : not found 
Checking for program /root/virtualenvt/draw/bin/python-config,python3.2-config,python-   config-3.2,python3.2m-config : /root/virtualenvt/draw/bin/python3.2-config 
Checking for header Python.h                                                                                       : :-( 
Asking python-config for the flags (pyembed)                                                                       : yes 
Getting pyembed flags from python-config                                                                           : yes 
Asking python-config for the flags (pyext)                                                                         : yes 
Getting pyext flags from python-config                                                                             : Could not build python extensions 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /root/pycairo/build_directory/config.log)
```

Any ideas why `python ./waf configure --prefix=/usr` cannot find `Python.h`?  This file is located in virtaulenv directory

```
(draw)[root@collabdraw pycairo]# ls ~/virtualenvt/draw/include/python3.2m/Python.
Python.h  ##### This is the file
```

Comment: Because you didn't tell it where to find Python.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it appears that would not be a problem: configure did find, for example, `/root/virtualenvt/draw/bin/python3.2-config`. The latter should really tell where to find `Python.h`, which for whatever reason it fails to do.

Comment: Then you should file a bug.

Comment: @zipc: from what I can see from the installation script and giving it a quick try myself, the installation is horrendously bugged. Perhaps you should try [cairocffi](http://pythonhosted.org/cairocffi/) instead, which at least follows a normal `distutils` installation.